# Advanced stacked bar chart ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

Say I have the data frame:

```
 df<-structure(list(predworker = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 
                 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 
                          8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
11, 11, 11, 11, 11
), worker = c(1, 14, 11, 19, 13, 23, 3, 15, 20, 6, 15, 3, 5, 
          4, 22, 5, 21, 11, 14, 4, 15, 23, 6, 20, 3, 17, 16, 8, 9, 7, 8, 
          17, 9, 16, 7, 17, 9, 8, 16, 7, 10, 19, 2, 15, 14, 14, 1, 11, 
          19, 13), finalratio = c(0.358338156170776, 0.328697413978311, 
                   0.200283479825366, 0.0634027658799677, 0.049278184145579, 0.245483741112573, 
                   0.216351263581975, 0.211285529819829, 0.171813670019988, 0.155065795465635, 
                   0.216637792442049, 0.21365067362223, 0.20254559121035, 0.184813787488195, 
                   0.182352155237176, 0.257680316012908, 0.233934275233779, 0.18618378722994, 
                   0.173241645742261, 0.14895997578111, 0.295633225885233, 0.197824577675154, 
                   0.173926460086197, 0.169883366487268, 0.162732369866148, 0.312634332494825, 
                   0.213471605336063, 0.168500990861721, 0.156199312722058, 0.149193758585333, 
                   0.288139828063799, 0.249716321272007, 0.228189414450808, 0.132448859555662, 
                   0.101505576657724, 0.28062982129018, 0.24896481457126, 0.185822099676468, 
                   0.175529116141424, 0.109054148320668, 0.843396823680576, 0.0488581484138975, 
                   0.0419903739183709, 0.0332313337137541, 0.0325233202734015, 0.354288383060293, 
                   0.308159669367751, 0.222981515774462, 0.0731493536310783, 0.0414210781664159
          ), rank = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
                  4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
                  5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
                  1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L)), 
       .Names = c("predworker", "worker", "finalratio",  "rank"), 
      row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df","tbl", "data.frame"), 
       vars = "predworker", drop = TRUE, 
      indices = list( 0:4, 5:9, 10:14, 15:19, 20:24, 25:29, 30:34, 35:39, 40:44, 
                     45:49), 
      group_sizes = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), 
      biggest_group_size = 5L, labels = structure(list(predworker = c(1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11)), 
       row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame", vars = "predworker", 
                   drop = TRUE, .Names = "predworker"))
```

which looks as follows:

```
predworker worker finalratio  rank
   <dbl>  <dbl>      <dbl> <int>
     1.     1.     0.358      1
     1.    14.     0.329      2
     1.    11.     0.200      3
     1.    19.     0.0634     4
     1.    13.     0.0493     5
     3.    23.     0.245      1
```

I'm trying to do a stacked bar chart using `ggplot2`. I'm looking for something similar to this

[image]

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(predworker) ,y = finalratio, fill = factor(rank))) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

However, there are some other details I do not know how to add to this plot:

1. I'd like to order each bar by rank (i.e. I want the longest bar at the beginning from the bottom. Opposite of what is now.)
2. How can I do two subplots in the same figure. Say I want the first 6 bars in one subplot and the rest in another subplot, but self-contained (sort of a `facet` in ggplot.)
3. How can I write a value within each bar for each category? For instance, for each `rank`, I'd like to write the corresponding `finalratio` and the `worker` (other column) value within the limits of each sub-bar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. To order bars by rank you need to reorder the factor levels, from 5 to 1.
2. You could subset the data by predworker and use something like `gridExtra::gridarrange` or `cowplot::plot_grid` to combine subplots. Or: you could add another column to indicate facets and facet on that.
3. You use `geom_text`. You'll want to round `finalratio` or there will be too many digits.

Putting it all together: I'm using the facet approach and ungrouping your grouped tibble because it interferes with `mutate`:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(facet = ifelse(predworker > 7, 2, 1), 
         rank = factor(rank, levels = 5:1), 
         predworker = factor(predworker)) %>% 
  group_by(predworker) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(predworker, finalratio)) + 
  geom_col(aes(fill = rank)) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = paste(worker, "=", round(finalratio, digits = 2))),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) + 
  facet_grid(~facet, scales = "free_x")
```

[image]

Or to facet vertically:

```
df %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(facet = ifelse(predworker > 7, 2, 1), 
         rank = factor(rank, levels = 5:1), 
         predworker = factor(predworker)) %>% 
  group_by(predworker) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(predworker, finalratio)) + 
  geom_col(aes(fill = rank)) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = paste(worker, "=", round(finalratio, digits = 2))),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) + 
  facet_wrap(~facet, scales = "free_x", ncol = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: This is fantastic! what about doing `facet` vertically?

Comment: `facet_grid(facet ~ .)`

Comment: Nice. However, is it possible to have it right below the one on top? SInce they have different `predworker`, the one on the bottom is moved to the right. Basically, we need  to reset the `predworker ` for the bottom figure.

Comment: `facet_wrap(~facet, scales = "free_x", ncol = 1)`

Comment: one last question: what if I want to write what is inside each bar in two lines?